# INVALID_PATCH_PATH error while using patch/updating the interval unit in PayPal plan update API

Tags: django, api, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I used the details in body as

```
[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/billing_cycles/frequency/interval_unit",
    "value": "MONTH"
  }
]
```

I get the output as follows

```
{
    "name": "INVALID_REQUEST",
    "message": "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.",
    "debug_id": "7e77554e0bd6d",
    "details": [
        {
            "field": "/0/path",
            "value": "/billing_cycles/frequency/interval_unit",
            "location": "body",
            "issue": "INVALID_PATCH_PATH",
            "description": "The specified field cannot be patched."
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#INVALID_REQUEST",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

what is the correct body data to pass to update the **interval_unit** of the PayPal plan data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>        "issue": "INVALID_PATCH_PATH",
>        "description": "The specified field cannot be patched."
> ```

The error message is correct, that field cannot be patched.

See [the update API call's documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_patch) for fields that can patched.

If you need a plan with different billing cycles, create a new plan.

Comment: thanks, so it cannot be patched, so if I need to delete the plan the only option is to make it inactive right? can you share the JSON body for that ? i tried [
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/status",
    "value": "INACTIVE"
  }
] but cant make it inactive

Comment: So you're looking for the 'deactivate plan' API call ... https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_deactivate

Comment: I was actually looking for an API to delete the plan with the plan id, but it appears PayPal does not provide such an option